# Ask about past day

Tags: grammaticality

I want to ask about past day to one of my friend. So,is this right sentence ??
"Who remind you this day ?" If not, please correct this ,and also explain what's wrong in this.

Comment: This is just a guess, because I am not sure what you are asking.   "What reminds you of yesterday?"  or, maybe "Who reminded you of yesterday?"

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the day that just ended, or the working day that just ended, and you want to know whether it was a good one or not, you can ask: "How was your day?"